# Determine the Barangay of a location

Tags: geojson, reverse-geocoding

I have a project that requires to determine the barangay (barrio/subdivision) of a location(latitude and longitude). Is there an API out there that I can use?

In the Philippines, an address must include a Barangay. An example format of an address would be like `[House No.][Street][Barangay][City][Region]`.
I tried to search in Google Maps API and LocationIQ API but the responses doesn't include barangays.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I had not found any Maps API that provides this data. But I do found a workaround for this by getting the polygons of all barangays from [geojsonph](https://github.com/macoymejia/geojsonph) *(which is in [GeoJson format](https://geojson.org/))*, then checking if the coordinates is inside that polygon using `getContainers()` of [geojson-geometries-lookup's](https://github.com/simonepri/geojson-geometries-lookup) library.

```js
// getBarangay.js

import GeoJsonGeometriesLookup from 'geojson-geometries-lookup'
import geoJson from 'Barangays.json'

export default function(lat, long) {
  const glookup = new GeoJsonGeometriesLookup(geoJson)

  const point = {type: "Point", coordinates: [long, lat]}
  const containersCount = glookup.countContainers(point)

  if(containersCount == 0){
    // no barangays found
    return null
  }else{
    // coordinate is inside a polygon
    let result = glookup.getContainers(point, options)
    return result
  }
}
```

The `getContainers(point)` will check all the given polygons inside the `Barangays.json` that contains the `point`, then returns the object in geojson format.

Then, if you want to get the name of the Barangay:

```js
  let long = 120.9725526
  let lat = 14.5945641
  let res = getBarangay(lat, long)
  console.log(res.properties.NAME_3)
```

However, this solution is not that optimal since you need to load the Barangay.json everytime the `getBarangay()` function is called, and there's 42,046 barangays in the Philippines as of now (2020). It would still be best if there's an API for this and we can just send a coordinate, and it will give back the barangay where it belongs.